# At equilibrium, which one of the following is always Zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, enthalpy, entropy, free-energy

At equilibrium, which one of the following is always zero?

(A)∆H
(B)∆S(Total)
(C)∆S(System)
(D)∆G°

I know that at equilibrium ∆G=0, and was facing difficulty in connecting the above mentioned thermodynamical parameters to equilibrium. Can someone help me regarding this? (I am an undergraduate student and don't want to dig deep into this. Please keep things simple for me.)

Comment: If you know that at equilibrium ∆G=0, isn't that enough to answer this question?

Comment: Here is a hint:  For an ideal constant temperature reservoir as the surroundings,  what is $\Delta S$ of the surroundings if the system undergoes a change at constant pressure?

Comment: Be aware that in contrary to $\Delta G$, $\Delta G^{\circ}$ is independent on being in equilibrium and is zero just accidentally.

Comment: This question is potentially misleading. It would be better to use differential (d) rather than finite (∆) differences.

Comment: See other posts, eg https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124412/what-is-wrong-in-this-argument-that-dg-must-always-be-zero/ and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51732/what-is-the-difference-between-the-equilibrium-position-and-the-equilibrium-cons/51735#51735 and many more....

Comment: See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41862/what-is-the-difference-between-%e2%88%86g-and-%e2%88%86g